# How do I generate a filtered set of available font family names? (like in Pages or TextEdit)

Tags: cocoa, nsfont, nsfontmanager

I want to make a popup button like the one in Pages.app (or in TextEdit.app) whose menu is a filtered list of font families.

I can get an array of available font family names from `[NSFontManager availableFontFamilies]`, but this provides far more font families than are in Pages's popup menu.

On the other hand, I can get what seems to be the correctly filtered set of font descriptors from `[NSFontCollection fontCollectionWithName:NSFontCollectionUser]`, but that includes each member of the family as well (italic, bold, etc). I don't want to include each member in my popup, only the family names.

I want the **filtered** set of **family** names.

The names I get out of the `NSFontManager` seem sanitized for UI, whereas the name values I get out of font descriptor's attributes dictionary (`[myFontDescriptor fontAttributes][NSFontNameAttribute]`) are not. So I can't just make a simple set intersection of the two groups based on the string values, the same things might have different names.

Comment: Have you looked at `NSFontFamilyAttribute` and `NSFontVisibleNameAttribute`?

Comment: @KenThomases Yes. I iterated over the array of fontDescriptors returned from the fontCollection, logging the attributes dictionary of each one, but the only keys each time were `NSFontNameAttribute` (with values like "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", etc) and `NSCTFontDesignLanguagesAttribute` (in my case, always with values of "en").

Comment: `NSFontDescriptor` is a little strange in my testing. If you log it directly or you request its `-fontAttributes`, you may get very few attributes. However, if you invoke its `-objectForKey:` method, you can get more.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you. There it is. Do you want to write up a quick answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-[NSFontDescriptor objectForKey:]` to retrieve attributes not present in the `-fontAttributes` dictionary. If you use the attribute key `NSFontFamilyAttribute`, that gives you the font family name. Applying that to each font descriptor in `[NSFontCollection fontCollectionWithName:NSFontCollectionUser]` should give you what you need.

Comment: I've read and reread class headers, documentation, articles, blog posts, etc., and not a single source (that I've laid eyes on) mentions what you've so eloquently stated here. You've just saved my sanity. Why is there not a single place in the docs that states, "Use the `objectForKey:` method to retrieve attributes not found in the `fontAttributes` dictionary?!" I mean, the documentation I have locally does seem to have some stuff missing (since Swift came about), but you'd think they'd have fixed most of that by now… Oh well. I just wanted to say thanks. Your answer is **much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

```
    let collection = NSFontCollection(name: "Fixed Width")
    var names = [String]()
    for description in (collection?.matchingDescriptors)!{
        let name = description.fontAttributes[NSFontNameAttribute] as! String
        names.append(name)

    }
    print(names)
```

here is my code to save someone some time

**Swiftlier**

```
let collection = NSFontCollection(name: NSFontCollection.Name(rawValue: "Fixed Width"))
let names = collection?.matchingDescriptors?.compactMap { $0.fontAttributes[.name] as? String }
```

Assuming `names` isn't nil, you can unique them (as you should) by creating a set with them via `Set(names)`.

Comment: I added a Swiftlier approach to this answer. :-)